# How do I add Websphere Application Server 8.0 to IBM Rational Application Developer 8.5.5

Tags: websphere, ibm-rational

I am using the IBM Rational Application Developer8.5.5.

I want to know How do I add an older "Runtime Environment" Websphere Application Server 8.0  to RAD 8.5.5 ?

Within RAD's view, I cannot add a WAS 8.0 server. If I click on the "download server adapters" link, it does not list Websphere 8.0  In the installation Manager I can see WAS 8.0 installed.

I have both RAD 7.5.5 and RAD 8.5.5 installed on my machine in different directories and RAD 8.5.5 and WAS 8.0 also installed in different directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most probable reason is that you didn't install WAS 8.0 development tools it during RAD installation.
Start Installation Manager and click Modify, then select your RAD installation.

Verify that in Server tools you have both WAS 8.5 and WAS 8.0 development tools installed (by default if I remember only 8.5 is selected).

Once you install 8.0 development tools, you will be able to add WAS server in the Servers view.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I have every WAS 8 component installed. Do you need a jdk 8 to see a WAS 8?

Comment: @Luke - which version of RAD and WAS do you have? WAS v8.0 supports only jdk6, so jdk8 will not help you.

Comment: Thanks, I manged it. What I was doing was serching server tools under WAS installation, instead of RAD installation.